# "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set" in code running perfectly last Friday

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code to color a column chart according to cell color in defined labels from A1 to A4 cells. It was running last Friday but now the line .Points(iCategory).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rCategory.Interior.Color gives an error.

```
Sub ColorByCategoryLabel()
  Dim rPatterns As Range
  Dim iCategory As Long
  Dim vCategories As Variant
  Dim rCategory As Range

  Set rPatterns = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    vCategories = .XValues
    For iCategory = 1 To UBound(vCategories)
      Set rCategory = rPatterns.Find(What:=vCategories(iCategory))
      .Points(iCategory).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rCategory.Interior.Color
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `rCategory` is `Nothing`. The `.Find` is not returning anything. To test it, change your code to this.

```
For iCategory = 1 To UBound(vCategories)
    Set rCategory = rPatterns.Find(What:=vCategories(iCategory))

    If rCategory Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox vCategories(iCategory) & " Not Found"
    Else
        .Points(iCategory).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rCategory.Interior.Color
    End If
Next
```

Check if you are referring to the  right sheet and searching something that actually exists.

Comment: Ok, resolved! There was no reference in A1 to A4, I had the formula  refereing to another cell where the text really is. Funny thing is this worked on Friday and not on Monday. I guess Excel was tired from a long week :D